# HTTP Strict Transport Security global cert refresh

Tags: ssl-certificate, lighttpd, lets-encrypt

So, I probably screwed up when I set up HSTS and didn't refresh my certificate in time.  Browsers now have a cache of my old certificate and don't seem to be contacting my server to request a fresh cert.  Is there some server trick to force clients to refresh an out of date certificate on an HSTS enabled server?

Using lighttpd and letsencrypt.

Comment: What does happen on the clients? Any error messages?

Comment: The clients are getting a date range error.

Comment: 1.) Why don't you just refresh your cert? 2.) Try to set the HSTS header to `max_age=0`.

Comment: 1) I did.  2) I removed HSTS headers to no effect.

Comment: Could you please provide the domain / url? Also: I didn't advise to remove the HSTS header, but to set `max_age` to `0`.

Comment: Tried that too, but same result.  http://highaltitudearchery.com (https://highaltitudearchery.com)

Comment: The webserver sends an expired cert. You refreshed the cert, you wrote? If so, you should check that (and your config).

Comment: Working now for me, using Chrome and Chomium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that lighttpd needs to have the private key and certificate concatenated.  After running the refresh for letsencrypt I just had to regenerate the `ssl.pem` by running:

```
cat privkey.pem cert.pem > ssl.pem
```

Feeling a little silly.